# What is the (kinetic) energy range of a particle in Bose condensate?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

Bose–Einstein condensate (BEC) is a state of matter that is typically formed when a gas of bosons at low densities is cooled to temperatures very close to absolute zero (−273.15 °C or −459.67 °F).

In this [link](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.31.410&rep=rep1&type=pdf) it says:

> The kinetic energy of a Bose condensate is on the order of one
> nanokelvin.

This is confusing to me, as i though kelvin was units for temperature only.

What is (kinetic) energy range of a typical particle in Bose condensate.

Comment: You can convert temperature (Kelvin) to energy by multiplying the Boltzmann constant $k_B$

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside that, as the comment points out, energy and temperature are related by: $E = k_B T$, where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant.

For BECs specifically, "kinetic energy" might mean two things.

Usually, the BEC is stationary, so there is no translational centre-of-mass motion (unless you kick it). So it's not usually kinetic energy is that sense.

Kinetic energy usually refers to the "quantum kinetic energy" or quantum pressure:
$$ E_k = \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\, \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} |\nabla \sqrt{n}|^2, $$ which quantifies the energy stored in the gas because of its spatial distribution. In a free gas, the cloud would be uniform density, no curvature, hence zero "kinetic" energy.